# Методология разработки различных версий продукта

Tags: git

Столкнулся с задачей, но не совсем понимаю, как правильно ее решить.
Есть сервис имеющий определенный функционал (криптовалютный торговый робот)
В процессе эволюции проекта, так вышло что на данный момент, существуют три версии данного проекта - две различные торговые стратегии и мониторинг ситуации на рынке. Все версии используют одинаковый функционал, но из-за мелких (но важных) особенностей/отличий мне приходится каждый сервис разрабатывать в отдельной ветке, при этом чтобы поменять какой-либо основной функционал, мне приходится руками править его во всех трех ветках, (править в одной и делать merge в остальные я тоже не могу, т.к. некоторый базовый функционал в этих ветках отличается)
Есть ли какой-либо подход, к такой ситуации?

Comment: Да, есть. Называется git rebase

Comment: А нельзя ль все эти особенности сделать в одной-единственной версии и просто включать и выключать их через настройки сервиса?

Comment: Поддержу @PavelMayorov, выделите базовый функционал в отдельную ветку (master), а поверх создайте ветки с продуктами (prod1, prod2, ...) и делайте в них `git rebase`, если что-то меняется в базовом функционале. Если же rebase не подходит по каким-то причинам (много разработчиков, код считается опубликованным среди заинтересованных лиц, прочее), то тогда можно пользоваться back-merge (иными словами `git merge` в продуктовые ветки из базовой). Вариант, предложенный Баракиным, будет удобным только для мелких и нечастых изменений. Если их много, и проект огромен — замучаетесь.

Answer (score 1):

чтобы добавить какой-нибудь коммит в какую-нибудь ветку, можно воспользоваться командой `cherry-pick`.

переключаетесь на нужную ветку (в которую следует добавить коммит):

```
$ git checkout имя.ветки
```

и добавляете коммит:

```
$ git cherry-pick хэш.коммита
```

если возникнут конфликты — устраняете их в обычном порядке.